# Is there a way to use flutter to access twitter API without errors?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, twitter

I am just starting to learn flutter and would like to know how to access the endpoints of the twitter API for a project I was creating. I wanted to display a tweet at first ( eventually it would be a random tweet generated with a button.)

My code is given below:

```
import 'package:twitter_api/twitter_api.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(Twittwrapp());
}
final _oauth = new twitterApi(
  consumerKey: 'consumerkeyhere',
  consumerSecret: 'consumersecrethere',
  token: 'tokenhere',
  tokenSecret: 'tokensecrethere',
);
Future twitterRequest = _oauth.getTwitterRequest(
  "GET",
  "statuses/user_timeline.json",
  options: {
    "user_id": "19025957",
    "screen_name": "TTCnotices",
    "count": "20",
    "trim_user": "true",
    "tweet_mode": "extended",
  },
);
class Twittwrapp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _Twitte createState() => _Twitte();
}

class _Twitte extends State<Twittwrapp>{
  var tweet = await twitterRequest;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Text(tweet),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the error i get is XMLHTTPREQUEST.

Comment: I assume you replaced those strings with your actual API keys in the code and simply didn't put them here for security reasons ?

Comment: @sinanspd Yes bro I did this exactly for security reasons. I have twitter api keys from their dev. program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var response = await http.get(Uri.http('example.com', 'apiPath'), //without https:// http:// or www
      headers: <String, String>{
        'consumerKey': 'consumerkeyhere',
        'consumerSecret': 'consumersecrethere',
        'token': 'tokenhere',
        'tokenSecret': 'tokensecrethere',
        ...
      }
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // request successful
      print(response.body);
      getQuestion();
    } else {
      // request error
      print(response.statusCode); // compare this code with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status and find the problem
    }
```

Comment: Ok Bro ill try this in a bit and tell you if it worked or not.